# Apply Range for Class and ID in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had created `accordion layout using html and CSS`. I will create `many parent row in an loop using JavaScript`, so i don't know the exact parent count to apply CSS.  To went for range specification like `[class*="tabb"] and [id*="tabb"]`, MY try has been commented in the below code. As of now it not working as accordion way, its simply opens all parent row and I'm unable to collapse it again.

Guys please help me out from this.

**My Try code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        header {
            background-color:#212121;
            box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px #111111;
            display:block;
            height:70px;
            position:relative;
            width:100%;
            z-index:100;
        }
        header h2{
            font-size:22px;
            font-weight:normal;
            left:50%;
            margin-left:-400px;
            padding:22px 0;
            position:absolute;
            width:540px;
        }
        header a.stuts,a.stuts:visited{
            border:none;
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#fcfcfc;
            font-size:14px;
            left:50%;
            line-height:31px;
            margin:23px 0 0 110px;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
        }
        header .stuts span {
            font-size:22px;
            font-weight:bold;
            margin-left:5px;
        }
        .container {
            height: 600px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .content {
            margin:0 auto;
            width:900px;
        }

        .accordion {
            color: #000000;
            margin: 50px auto;
            position: relative;
            width: 590px;
        }
        .accordion span {
            display: none
        }
        .tabs {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .tabs dl dd a {
            background-color: #C8CEFF;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-color:#ccc;border-bottom-color:#aaa;
            display: block;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 32px;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;

            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#ffffffff,EndColorStr=#ffe0e0e0);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
            background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#fff),color-stop(100%,#e0e0e0));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);

            -moz-transition: 0.3s;
            -ms-transition: 0.3s;
            -o-transition: 0.3s;
            -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
        .tabs dl dd div {
            background-color: #FFF;
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;

            box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;

            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }
        .tabs dl dd div p {
            color: #444444;
            font-size: 13px;
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: justify;
        }
        .tabs dl dd a:hover {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
        }
        .tabs dl dd a:active {
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#e6e6e6,EndColorStr=#dcdcdc);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#e6e6e6),color-stop(100%,#dcdcdc));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
        }


        #tabb1:target ~ .tabs .tabb1 dd div {
            height: 100px;
        }
        #tabb2:target ~ .tabs .tabb2 dd div {
            height: 345px;
        }

        #tabb1:target ~ .tabs .tabb1 dd a,
        #tabb2:target ~ .tabs .tabb2 dd a {
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#e6e6e6,EndColorStr=#dcdcdc);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#e6e6e6),color-stop(100%,#dcdcdc));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);

            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
        }

        /*[id*="tabb"]:target ~ .tabs [class*="tabb"] dd div {
            height: 100px;
        }

        [id*="tabb"]:target ~ .tabs [class*="tabb"] dd a {
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#e6e6e6,EndColorStr=#dcdcdc);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#e6e6e6),color-stop(100%,#dcdcdc));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);

            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
        }*/
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="accordion">
                <span id="tabb1"></span>
                <span id="tabb2"></span>
                <div class="tabs">
                    <dl class="tabb1">
                        <dd>
                            <a href="#tabb1">Tab #1</a>
                            <div><p>Tab1</p></div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl class="tabb2">
                        <dd>
                            <a href="#tabb2">Tab #2</a>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                   Tab2
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** My try has been commented as below

```
/*[id*="tabb"]:target ~ .tabs [class*="tabb"] dd div {
            height: 100px;
        }

        [id*="tabb"]:target ~ .tabs [class*="tabb"] dd a {
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#e6e6e6,EndColorStr=#dcdcdc);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#e6e6e6),color-stop(100%,#dcdcdc));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e6e6e6 0,#dcdcdc 100%);

            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
        }*/
```

How can i specify the range to achieve my accordion functionality ?

Comment: If you want every element to have the same style, put them in the same container and give the container a CSS class; or use a CSS class on every element; they will have the same style because that's how the class selector works. Why do you need to apply wildcard rule in the CSS block? Also it's a lot easier to dynamically change the output in JavaScript as opposed to wrestling with CSS.

Comment: I tried no luck @Schien. I has posted my code above, It will be great if you specify exact where i need to do what.... Would be better for me.

Comment: In what way are tabb1 and tabb2 different? If you'd like them to look the same, give them the same class "tab". It is not a crime to use inline styles to specify the difference in your case, you know?

Comment: yes, i agree. But i require accordion functionality to work. Initially tabb1 will be open, if i click tabb2, tabb1 will collapse and tabb2 will open and vice-versa. My main problem is that functionality is not working @Schien. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Just realized that you wanted the accordion style instead of just tabs. The principles are the same. Just style them differently!

Comment: Thanks for posting @Schien. But i require Accordion only. The problem is on the keyword "target" in "#tabb2:target ~ .tabs .tabb2 dd div"  on my above code.

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Tpzp/ @KrunalPanchal

Comment: Have you tried my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448581/apply-range-for-class-and-id-in-css/21543034#21543034

Comment: IT worked pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have tried to solve your issue:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#tabb"]', function() {
    $('a[href^="#tabb"]').siblings('div').css('height', 0)
    if ($(this).siblings('div').height() == 0) {
      $(this).siblings('div').css('height', 100)
    } else {
      $(this).siblings('div').css('height', 0)
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px #111111;
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  padding: 22px 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 540px;
}

header a.stuts,
a.stuts:visited {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 31px;
  margin: 23px 0 0 110px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

header .stuts span {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.container {
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
}

.accordion {
  color: #000000;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 590px;
}

.accordion span {
  display: none
}

.tabs {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs dl dd a {
  background-color: #C8CEFF;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr=#ffffffff, EndColorStr=#ffe0e0e0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e0e0e0 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e0e0e0 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e0e0e0 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(100%, #e0e0e0));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e0e0e0 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #e0e0e0 100%);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.tabs dl dd div {
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs dl dd div p {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.tabs dl dd a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}

.tabs dl dd a:active {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr=#e6e6e6, EndColorStr=#dcdcdc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #e6e6e6), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
}

#tabb1:target~.tabs .tabb1 dd a,
#tabb2:target~.tabs .tabb2 dd a {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr=#e6e6e6, EndColorStr=#dcdcdc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #e6e6e6), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e6e6e6 0, #dcdcdc 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion">
    <span id="tabb1"></span>
    <span id="tabb2"></span>
    <div class="tabs">
      <dl class="tabb1">
        <dd>
          <a href="#tabb1">Tab #1</a>
          <div>
            <p>Tab1</p>
          </div>
        </dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="tabb2">
        <dd>
          <a href="#tabb2">Tab #2</a>
          <div>
            <p>
              Tab2
            </p>
          </div>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated fiddle:

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/9Tpzp/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.tabview{display:none;}
</style>
<span id="tab0" onclick="showtab(0);">Tab 1</span>
<span id="tab1" onclick="showtab(1);">Tab 2</span>
<span id="tab2" onclick="showtab(2);">Tab 3</span>
<div id="tabview0" class="tabview">View 1</div>
<div id="tabview1" class="tabview">View 2</div>
<div id="tabview2" class="tabview">View 3</div>

<script>
function showtab(){
  //i'm hardcoding 3 here; 
  //but you should know the number of tabs as you're generating them

  var len=3;

  for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
    document.getElementById('tab'+i).style.fontWeight='normal';
    document.getElementById('tabview'+i).style.display='none';
  }

  document.getElementById('tab'+i).style.fontWeight='bold';
  document.getElementById('tabview'+i).style.display='block';

}

showtab(0); //open the first tab by default
</script>
```

Comment: It does'nt help me... Thanks for your post. Still im trying.