# Regular expression on CSS

Tags: jquery, regex, css

My full code is posted here [Apply Range for Class and ID in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448581/apply-range-for-class-and-id-in-css)

My JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9Tpzp/

My existing CSS code is like below

```
#tab1:target ~ .tabs .tab1 dd div {
   height: 28px;
}
#tab2:target ~ .tabs .tab2 dd div {
   height: 28px;
}
#tab3:target ~ .tabs .tab3 dd div {
   height: 28px;
}
#tab4:target ~ .tabs .tab4 dd div {
   height: 28px;
}
```

I changed as below

```
[id*='tab']:target ~ .tabs [class*='tab'] dd div {
    height : 28px;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="accordion">
                <span id="tab1"></span>
                <span id="tab2"></span>
                <div class="tabs">
                    <dl class="tab1">
                        <dd>
                            <a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a>
                            <div><p>Tab1</p></div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl class="tab2">
                        <dd>
                            <a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                   Tab2
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Now how can i specify the number range 1-4 in that regular expression.

If it is impossible in CSS, Can we achieve through any other way like jquery,etc,.

Comment: If you mean you want the class regex to be something like `tab[1-4]`, I don't think CSS supports that.

Comment: can we achieve through any other way  like jquery, etc,. @mathematical.coffee

Comment: Could you get rid of that .tab* class?

Comment: .tab* class is required @j08691

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Try this 
span[id^='tab']:target ~ .tabs dl[class^='tab'] dd div {
    height : 28px;
}

Comment: It's not working @KrunalPanchal

Comment: It may help to make a JSFiddle that we can edit to try to make work :)

Comment: that will cool @Sam Sullivan

Comment: post my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Tpzp/ @SamSullivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using jquery. Below is the fix.

```
$(document).on('click','a[href^="#tab"]',function(){
                $('a[href^="#tab"]').siblings('div').css('height',0);
                if($(this).siblings('div').height() == 0){
                        $(this).siblings('div').css('height',28); 
            }
                else {
                $(this).siblings('div').css('height',0);
            }       
            })
```